# Separating a column data into multiple columns in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue, hive-query

I have a sample data for a device which contains two controller and it's version. The sample data is as follows:

```
device_id   controller_id  versions
123          1             0.1
123          2             0.15
456          2             0.25
143          1             0.35
143          2             0.36
```

This above data should be in the below format:

```
device_id   1st_ctrl_id_ver   2nd_ctrl_id_ver
123          0.1              0.15
456          NULL             0.25
143          0.35             0.36
```

I used the below code which is not working:

```
select
device_id,
case when controller_id="1" then versions end as 1st_ctrl_id_ver,
case when controller_id="2" then versions end as 2nd_ctrl_id_ver       
from device_versions
```

The ouput which i got is:

```
device_id   1st_ctrl_id_ver   2nd_ctrl_id_ver
123          0.1              NULL
123          NULL             0.15
456          NULL             0.25
143          0.35             NULL
143          NULL             0.36
```

I don't want the Null values in each row.Can someone help me in writing the correct code?

Comment: Could you please add your **expected output?**

Comment: Actually all your tags are irrelevant. The question is about standard SQL.

Comment: @ Shu the expected output is below the sample data

Comment: @ Samson i use this in hive query editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "fold" all lines with a given key to a single line, you have to run an *aggregation*. Even if you don't really aggregate values in practise.

Something like
`select device_id,`
`MAX(case when controller_id="1" then versions end) as 1st_ctrl_id_ver,`
`MAX(case when controller_id="2" then versions end) as 2nd_ctrl_id_ver`
`from device_versions`
`GROUP BY device_id`

But be aware that this code will work if and only if you have at most one entry per controller per device, and any controller with a version higher than 2 will be ignored. In other words it is rather brittle (but you can't do better in SQL anway)

Comment: i have few data with 3 to 4 records for each ID. As said, ID with 4 records are ignored.. Is there any other way?

Comment: Duh, my final comment was confusing. Should make sense now > if you have 100 different controllers you will need 100 different `case when` clauses.